# Is there a way to write these ifs nicer?

Tags: python, control-structure

I need to write these four `if`s in Python. Notice what it does, is changing between four possible states in a loop: `1,0 -> 0,1 -> -1,0 -> 0,-1` and back to first.

```
if [dx, dy] == [1,0]:
    dx, dy = 0, 1
if [dx, dy] == 0, 1:
    dx, dy = -1, 0
if [dx, dy] == [-1, 0]
    dx, dy = 0, -1
if [dx, dy] == [0, -1]:
    dx, dy = 1, 0
```

Can anyone suggest me a better/nicer way to write this?

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but it looks like a state transition table, so I would stick them in a dict where the key is the from state, and the value is the to state.

Comment: Did you mean `elif` on lines 3,5,7?  Because as it stands 1,0 would be taken on a wild goose chase back to 1,0 again!

Comment: @wim: Actually, `1, 0` would become `0, 1` as expected, since `[dx, dy] == 0, 1` is always false.

Comment: false?  in this context, it's a syntax error isn't it...?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

```
dx, dy = -dy, dx
```

When in doubt, apply maths. ;)

Answer (score 56):

Magnus' suggestion is undeniably the right answer to your question as posed, but *generally speaking,* you want to use a dictionary for problems like this:

```
statemap = {(1, 0): (0, 1), (0, 1): (-1, 0), (-1, 0): (0, -1), (0, -1): (1, 0)}

dx, dy = statemap[dx, dy]
```

Even in this case I *could* argue using a dictionary is better, since it's clear that there are exactly four states and that they repeat, but it's hard to resist the sheer beauty of *all teh maths.*

By the way, the code in your question has a bug in it, and, assuming that the values you test for are the only possible values, is equivalent to:

```
dx, dy = 1, 0
```

The bug is that you need `elif` for the second and subsequent conditions, otherwise you're continuing to test `dx` and `dy` after changing them. If they're `1` and `0`, then *all your conditions will be true* and they end up the same at the end! If they start out as `0` and `1` then the second and all subsequent conditions will be true, and you again end up with `1, 0`. And so on...

Answer (score 31):

Just extending Magnus answer. If you imagine [dx, dy] as a vector, what you're actually doing is a [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) of 90 degrees (or PI/2).

To calculate this, you can use the following transformation:

[image: two dimensional rotation]

Which in your case translate to:

```
x = x * cos(90) - y * sin(90)
y = x * sin(90) + y * cos(90)
```

Since `sin(90) = 1` and `cos(90) = 0` we simplify it to:

```
x, y = -y, x
```

And there you have it!

Comment: Although Magnus Hoff may have +1 for elegance, I believe this should be +1 for the derivation of elegance.

Comment: It also exhibits the relationship between Magnus Hoff's answer and mine.

Answer (score 18):

The values you're working with appear to be a unit vector that continuously rotates - in other words, a [phasor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor). [Complex numbers are coordinates](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ComplexNumbersArePoints), so:

```
# at initialization
phase = 1
# at the point of modification
phase *= 1j
dx, dy = phase.real, phase.imag
```

Assuming my interpretation of the meaning of the dx,dy values is correct, this gives you extra flexibility in case it turns out later that you want to rotate by some other amount in each step.

Answer (score 6):

While I would go with Magnus' answer, here's yet another approach for rotating over a set of values:

```
def rotate(*states):
    while 1:
        for state in states:
            yield state

for dx, dy in rotate((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)):
    pass
```

Note that there should be a `break` somewhere in the `for dx, dy` loop or else it will never end.

Comment: [`itertools.cycle(...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), while not an exact drop-in for your `rotate`, can solve the same problem.

Comment: Indeed, forgot about `cycle`. Thanks.